# ArrayList Object assigned to LIst Object internal working

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So far from most  the related posts i have understood  difference in usage between **ArrayList assigned to List ,and ArrayList assigned to ArrayList**

```
   ArrayList<String> arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String>      arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

And as a matter of fact the preferred methodology is  [**"Programming to Interface"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

```
   List<String>      arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

But my question is

- **Does the List object considered/becomes an ArrayList Object (ones ArrayList obj is assigned) ?**

  **or**
- **Does it remains  the same as a List Object?**

Thanks for  the reply in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the List object considered/becomes an ArrayList Object (ones ArrayList obj is assigned) ?

`List arrName` is a reference which is pointing to object of its implemented class `ArrayList`.

> Does it remains the same as a List Object?

List is an interface so you can not declare List object. It will remain object of ArrayList only. Just to point out, as the reference is of List so you can only call methods declared in List interface (which will call its implementation in ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

List never become a class and it's an interface.

```
   List<String>      arrName =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

In that above case `List` is holding a reference to the implemented Class `ArrayList`of it's type  with a name given  `arrName` .

Answer (score 1):

References are like *glasses*. If you wear green coloured glasses, the world looks green, if you wear blue coloured glasses, the world looks blue. **The world remains the same. Only how you see it changes**

Similarly, if you have an `ArrayList` instance and a reference to it, *if you want to call methods that are present only in `List` that are overriden by `ArrayList`, then use : `List<T> x = new ArrayList<>()`*.

*If you want to call only methods of `ArrayList`, then use `ArrayList<T> = new ArrayList<>`.

The second approach should be used because the right method of *the right kind of List* is always called. You can pass *any List instance* around by coding to the reference.